# PHP - access different pages

Tags: php, html

I want to make my php page like the following scenarios:

- If I click the "my account", it will link me to login page if I'm
  not logged into the site.
- If I click the "my account" and I'm
  already logged to the site, it will take me to the user account.

Answer (score 0):

You can PHP Sessions for this purpose.Have a look at the below example

[Login With Session](http://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/)

Answer (score 0):

You must set a session variable

**Login Page: login.php**
e.g.

```
    <?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php

if(($_POST['username']=="myusername") && ($_POST['password']=="password"))
    {
    $_SESSION["mysession"] = $_POST['username'];
    }
else {
?>
 <form action="" method="post">
  User Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
  <br>
  Password:<br>
  <input type="password" name="password" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<?php  }

?>
```

**My Account Page:**

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['mysession'])){
echo $_SESSION['mysession'];
}
else 
{
header("Location: http://example.com/login.php");
die();
}
?>
```